# A desktop app for viewing the latest updates to git repositories in real-time? (OS X)

Tags: macos, git, updates, feed

Does anyone know if there is a simple OS X app that can display real-time updates to git repositories?

Basically, I'm working on several repositories with multiple people, so normally I always have a Chrome tab open on auto-refresh in order to view the latest changes to the various repositories. But I do quite a bit of web browsing, so it's annoying always having to switch back to that tab whenever I want to see changes.

It would be nice if I could take advantage of the iMac's display resolution and have an app in the corner of the screen that displays real-time Git updates as they come in (or at the least, every few minutes or so). Sort of like an RSS or Twitter feed, I guess.

Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gitifier](http://psionides.github.com/Gitifier/) will show you growl notifications for new commits.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using free version of [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html) for SVN. Cross platform and relatively simple.

They have a product for Git as well that might work for you, [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html), which is free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this might be useful to you: [Gitfeed](https://github.com/scotchi/gitfeed)